# Contact form sends email but has no message

Tags: php, email, send, contact-form

I am having trouble with my PHP code for my website. The email is being sent but has no messages.

[This is the email I get when it sends. It's empty.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rjj1.png)

[Data I input in my contact form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWZUy.png)

I tested my php code without the css files and bootstrap, and received the email perfectly with the messages. But when I included everything, from css and bootstrap codes, I receive the email without any messages.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="contact-form bottom">
    <h2> We want to hear from you . Send us a message!</h2>
    <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="send_email_test.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="userName" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" name="userEmail" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email Id">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="userMessage" id="message" required class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Your text here"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['userName'];
$field_email = $_POST['userEmail'];
$field_subject = $_POST['userSubject'];
$field_message = $_POST['userMessage'];

$mail_to = 'info@mariamulan.com'; /* Add your email address here */
$subject = 'Message from website'.$field_name; /* Create your own subject */

$body_message .= 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'Email: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Subject: '.$field_subject."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Hey! Thanks for the message! We will try to reply to you as soon as possible!');
    window.location = 'index.html'; /* Where you want to get directed */
 </script>
<?php
} else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Sorry, your message was not sent! Please send an email to 
hello.mariamulan@gmail.com instead.');
    window.location = 'index.html'; /* Where you want to get directed 
*/
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

---

Comment: Check if `$_POST` has any data or everything is blank

Comment: In the email, everything is blank.

Comment: In the email, everything is blank, bcz `$_POST` variable is blank.

Comment: I might have confused you, I put data for  test run, but when I check the email, it's empty and included all the other css.

Comment: what's a `messafe` ?

Comment: How about enabling error_reporting, and checking your submit form for the right method= ?

Comment: I'm new to PHP, I'm not aware/unsure on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your form has the correct "name" attributes.
Your code is pretty dirty tho.

Comment: everything is correct. I tested the html and php, it worked perfectly fine but when I added it to my website with everything else, the email is empty.

Comment: This is really strange, could you do a vardump before sending the email an post the result

Comment: I tried adding in the vardump, then the form won't send. I'm note sure if I'm doing it right.  Is it worth mentioning that my website was from a bootstrap template?

Comment: @JaneDoe did you really test it? Two things... 1. There is no form input for userSubject ( that comes up as a notice warning... )  2. Note what you did for $headers that you didn't do for $body_message! That will generate another notice.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Yes I did. So I have to do it with the $headers.https://drive.google.com/a/benilde.edu.ph/file/d/14wvsz4IsCgvFBHQ_gw41Hib3Yu6pEo9m/view?usp=sharing             <this is the link for the photo.> it worked perfectly.